# what versions of cURL and OpenSSL do I need for https post

Tags: php, curl, https, openssl, libcurl

I'm getting my server set up for being to https post and ive read that some people have had issues with their cURL or OpenSSL libraries.  I dont want to get to far into this and get a probelm with my code (im completely new to php) just to realize that my code isnt bad, but rather my server settings.

Here's what i currently have installed:

libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5 
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

do i need to ask my hosting company to upgrade either of these?  or should i be all set to https post data to a third party?

Comment: (1) Do an HTTPS post, (2) Have the answer....

Comment: i actually have to learn how to do the https post first, so i just wanted to make sure I'm set up correctly.  if i get errors i want to be sure that it's because of my code and not my server configuration

Answer (score 0):

curl and libcurl have supported HTTPS POST for perhaps some ten years or so, and even if you have a VERY old release (see [releaselog](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/releases.html), your release is >5.5 years old) it worked back then too.

For a lot of other reasons however, including security vulnerabilities and hundreds of other bug fixes, you should still consider upgrading.